# buildforge problem

Tags: build, buildforge

when i tried to run the job i am getting the error saying that

**No server could be found matching all conditions**

please any one help me on this

Answer (score 1):

In buildforge, the job is assigned to a selector.
The selector can be thought of as a pointer to an object that can represent either the name of a server, or a set of servers that matches a set of criteria.
When the job executes, the selector for that step attempts to find the server based on the criteria defined in the selector conditions. If it can't find a server that matches the selection conditions, you get the posted error message.

In real life, this error usually indicates the following:
1. The agent on the server is dead, or the server is down. Run bfservertest (or test connection in the buildforge web UI) to see if the agent is functioning. Visit the machine remotely or in person to verify that the server is up. Try restarting the agent service if machine is up and connection test fails.
2. The selector is pointing to a non-existent server because you misspelled the server name.
3. You have conditions defined in the selector that unintentionally exclude all servers from being used.